# preg_match or preg_replace to get only number from html code

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, simple-html-dom

I am having a bit trouble to get only number from specific part of html code, i am parsing one page and output of content looks like this.

```
<div class="priceitem"> 1,098&nbsp;USD <span id="XUwt-price-mb-aE068a15dcca8E168a15dcca8-tooltipIcon" class="tooltip-icon afterPrice info-icon"> <svg class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="100%" height="100%"><use xlink:href="#common-icon-icon-info"></use></svg> </span> <br></div>
```

I am using simplehtmldom to get content, so everything inside `priceitem` get output with it. Can i somehow use preg_match to match pattern or preg_replace to get only price number like `1,098`.

The price can change so sometimes it will be only `29 usd` which will output `29&nbsp;USD`, sometimes price can be `305&nbsp;USD`, but over 1k it will have comma which i don't need really.

Here is my attempt on everything:

```
foreach($html->find('div.priceitem') as $element) {
    $pricenum = preg_match("/([^\s]+)/","", $element->innertext);
    echo $pricenum;
}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pattern that should get you all possible prices:

```
(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*)+(?=&nbsp;USD)
```

The idea is, the numbers are in blocks of 1-3 digits, groups with a leading comma are allowed but not required after a regular block. `&nbsp;USD` is as an anchor.

[Online sample](https://regex101.com/r/ZQCnDh/2/)

However, if you are only interested in the integer part, removing the comma is still the best option: `str_replace(',', '' , $string);`

Comment: This is awesome, thank you, i just found solution using combination of preg_match and preg_replace, but this is more foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

For int values it makes more sense to remove commas and then preg_match for /\d+/